# Upload and read Excel file with Image in Column

Tags: php, mysql, angular, excel, image

I am developing an Angular Application in that i am trying to upload an excel file, the excel file contains some text data in column and specifically one column contains an images in its rows like D1, D2, D3 and so on.

i am reading the excel file at my front end but i think it is not reading the image in the respective column on console.log it is giving me only text data in the columns

```
      <form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="Excel_Upload()" >

        <a id="excel_upload_label">Upload Excel</a>

        <input type="file" (change)="onEx_FileChange($event)" multiple="false">

        <button type = "submit" id="excel_upload_button">Upload Properties</button>

      </form>
```

onEx_FileChange(evt : any){

```
const target : DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);

if(target.files.length !== 1){
  alert("Multiple File upload");
}

const reader : FileReader = new FileReader(); 

reader.onload = (e : any) =>{
  const bstr: string = e.target.result;
  const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type: 'binary'});
  const wsname : string = wb.SheetNames[0];
  const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
  this.data = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header:1}));
  console.log(this.data); // on this console i am getting only text data

};
reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Pictures are supported only in paid version of sheetjs.

Comment: if i would have a paid version of sheetjs it will read image automatically from its respective row and column